# I can't add or remove a class

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to remove a class and add a class within one function. But when I click on the button nothing is happening.

This is my code

```js
function unlikeVerhaal(unlike) {
  unlike.preventDefault;
  document.querySelector('#unliked').classList.add('onzichtbaar');
  document.querySelector('#liked').classList.remove('onzichtbaar');
}

document.querySelector('.likebutton').addEventListener('submit', unlikeVerhaal);
```

```css
.onzichtbaar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <button type="submit" class="likebutton">
    <img src="icons/lined.png" alt="lined heart" class="unliked" id="unliked">
    <img src="icons/solid.png" alt="solid heart" id="liked" class="onzichtbaar">
  </button> 777
</li>
```

What I am trying to get is that the class is added to the first image and removed by the second image.

Comment: I'm almost positive that `<form>`s fire `submit` events, not `<buttons>`.

Comment: change event listener to click and remove that type property from button

Comment: also you shouldnt make 2 functions for like and unlike but rather toggle class in one function and have if condition in it because right now your code would require 2 buttons i dont know if you want it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will works as you expect:

```
function unlikeVerhaal(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    document.getElementById('unliked').classList.add('onzichtbaar');
    document.getElementById('liked').classList.remove('onzichtbaar'); 
} 

document.getElementById('likebutton').addEventListener('click', unlikeVerhaal);
```

Just change `submit` to `click` and remove `type` from button

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/79vc8jeh/2/)**

Update:

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/79vc8jeh/8/)**

Comment: Can you use a stack snippet instead of external fiddle?

Comment: @OgechiChibueze but fiddle works, take a look at console

Comment: @barmar what the problem, what's not a reason to downvote my anwser, i use what i'm like to use, stack snippet confuses me sometimes.

Comment: I just commented, didn't downvote. I never downvote an answer unless it's wrong. Stack snippet is very similar to jsfiddle, what's confusing about it?

Comment: @20yco yes I can see that it's working in fiddle, but when I copy it in my code it's not working. Should I copy a bigger part of my code and paste it here?

Comment: @barmar okay, sorry for that, confused that i can't see question when editing code ( to copy paste or read question again ), i need to close snippet -> read question again ( or small parts of question ) -> when search small button to edit existing snippet, aarrrrr

Comment: I agree, that's annoying. But once you've created the fiddle, you can easily copy/paste from it to a snippet.

Comment: @OgechiChibueze of course you need, and don't downvote please if it not works because you did something wrong

Comment: @OgechiChibueze i'm only changed the code that you represent here, so try to change only the code from fiddle, hope that helps

Comment: @20yco I am getting the error  "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @OgechiChibueze please see updated fiddle and copy HTML and JS from it

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use a combination of the three methods **`.contains()`**, **`.add()`** and **`.remove()`** from the **[element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** property along with a simple `if/else statement` (or a ternary operator if you prefer that) as can be seen in the **Code Snippet** below:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.likebutton');

function unlikeVerhaal() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("unliked");
    var l = document.getElementById("liked");
    
    if (ul.classList.contains("onzichtbaar")) {
        ul.classList.remove("onzichtbaar");
        l.classList.add("onzichtbaar");
        console.log("Inspect your elements to see the class switching!")
    } else {
        l.classList.remove("onzichtbaar");
        ul.classList.add("onzichtbaar");
        console.log("Inspect your elements to see the class switching!")
    }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", unlikeVerhaal)
```

```css
.onzichtbaar {background-color: green;}
```

```html
<li>
      <button type="button" class="likebutton">
      <div class="unliked" id="unliked">A</div>
      <div id="liked" class="onzichtbaar">B</div>
      </button> 777
</li>
```

---

You can either *inspect the elements* to see the class switching between the two or you can just watch the *green background styling* which is applied to an element with the `onzichtbaar` class name switching between the two.