# If/Else statement to show/hide element if class name present

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I can only use JavaScript on this particular CMS.
I need help getting a script that will only show an image IF a class name is present.
I'll be loading 3 images at the same time.
But I can only show a specific image IF the class name is present, and the OTHER images should be hidden if the OTHER class names are NOT present.

I haven't tried any other code, as I'm new to JavaScript and haven't found anything online that matches this situation to help me.

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] and show us what you're working with and what you've tried. Haven't written anything yet? The SO isn't the place for your question.

Comment: So onload/document ready, check to see if the class is there....

Comment: There's an almost same question asked barely 55min ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078864/i-cant-add-or-remove-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** need Javascript to do that:

```
images = document.querySelectorAll("images");

images.forEach((image) => {
    if(image.className === "yourClassName") {
        image.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        image.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

This code checks all images if "yourClassName" is present, and if not, hides them.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use CSS to do that like this:

```css
#container img {
     display: none;
}
#container img.className {
     display: block;
}
```

It is doable in javascript, but it's just not the prefered way in general for something that simple